# Mysql Auto update other record after insert new row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a mysql table profile_color:

[image]

Every time user Insert a row in this table, the ask is, if the value of default column is `"Yes"` in new row, I want to set old Yes value to `"No"` for that particular user.
Is there any way using trigger or any other option, I don't want to run update Query again.

Comment: Yes, you can use a trigger. Why don't you have a try?

Comment: Will users be inserting rows via SQL? If not, perhaps this is better suited to the application, or a stored procedure that inserts data and does this check.

Comment: ... or a `TRIGGER` so users can add rows on SQL and the application ;)